# How can I make svn store clear text passwords in Debian Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, svn, authentication

I am using an internal toy svn server, and svn client seems to be configured to store passwords in gnome-keyring by default. How can I disable it or at least switch to kwallet?

I am using Debian Testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~/.subversion/config`:

```
[auth]
password-stores = kwallet
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable gnome-keyring for one run of svn:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK= svn...
```

To disable gnome-keyring SSH support:

```
gnome-session-properties
Untick/uncheck SSH Key Agent
```

To disable gnome-keyring completely:

```
vi /etc/pam.d/gdm  # or kdm
Delete the pam_gnome_keyring.so line
```

See also: [GnomeKeyring/Ssh](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring/Ssh)

You may also want to change the value of the svn `store-plaintext-passwords` option.

See [Subversion 1.6 Release Notes - Prompting before storing passwords in plaintext form](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html#auth-related-improvements) for details.